# stop a function declared inside setInterval() using clearInterval()

Tags: jquery

How do i stop a function declared inside setInterval(), like

```
var start = function(){
    setInterval(function(){//DO SOMETHING},3000)
};

var stop = function() {
    clearInterval(start);
};

$('button.start').click(function(){
    start();
});

$('button.stop').click(function(){
    stop();
});
```

But still I am not able to stop the setInterval function here. Need a little help on that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare a variable `interval` .

setInterval will create a id.

then assign `setInterval` id into that `inertval` variable .

if wanna stop `setInterval` then pass `inertval` into `clearInterval`

Try like this

```
var interval;
var start = function(){
    interval=setInterval(function(){
       //DO SOMETHING
    },3000)
};

var stop = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is close, but not quite right.  `setInterval` returns an `intervalID` that can then be passed to `clearInterval`.

Something like this would work:

```
var start = function(){
    window.startIntervalID = setInterval(function(){//DO SOMETHING},3000)
};

var stop = function() {
    clearInterval(window.startIntervalID);
};
```

See MDN documentation for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).